# pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[]). How to pass a data which is with nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My data is like:

```
data = {'Sr.No.': Sr_no,
        'CompanyNames': Company_Names,
        'YourChoice1': ['45','45','45','45','45','45','45','45','45'],
        'YourChoice2': ['45','45','45','45','45','45','45','45','45'],
        'Bollinger Bands': {'Field1': ['45','45','45','45','45','45','45','45'],
                            'Field2': ['45','45','45','45','45','45','45','45'],
                            'Field3':['45','45','45','45','45','45','45','45']}
                           }
```

Which I am passing to the dataframe as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Sr.No.','CompanyNames','YourChoice1','YourChoice2','Bollinger Bands'])
```

But I am receiving error as:

> ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.

Can anyone help me with this?

The CSV file should look like:

[image]

I tried the 1st solution like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Sr.No.', 'CompanyNames','YourChoice1','YourChoice2'])
bbands = data.pop('Bollinger Bands')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(bbands)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=['','Bollinger Bands'])
```

But I have obtained the output as:

[image]

I want that 'Bollinger Bands' should be in only the first column not in all...'

The desired output is:

```
 |      |     |     |     |Bollinger Bands|        |        |
 |Sr.No.|Comp |     |     |Field1         |Field2  |Field3  |
```

Comment: Please, [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your code properly

Comment: Your data types are a mix of lists and dicts. And i'm not sure about `Sr_no` and `Company_Names`. Are they dicts/lists as well?

Comment: They are lists...

Comment: `Bollinger Bands` is a dict. You have to convert that to a list.

Comment: Actually, I am passing this dataframe into a csv file....

Comment: I have edit the problem with desired output of csv file....

Answer (score 4):

`pd.DataFrame` is expecting a dictionary with list values, but you are feeding an irregular combination of list *and* dictionary values.

Your desired output is distracting, because it does not conform to a regular `MultiIndex`, which *should* avoid empty strings as labels for the first level. Yes, you can obtain your desired output for presentation purposes, but it's not *advisable* to store your data in an unstructured way.

Instead, I suggest you flatten your dictionary *before* constructing your dataframe:

```
data.update(data.pop('Bollinger Bands'))
```

Then construct a regular dataframe with one header level:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Sr.No.','CompanyNames','YourChoice1','YourChoice2',
                                 'Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3'])
```

This gives:

```
   Sr.No.  CompanyNames YourChoice1 YourChoice2 Field1 Field2 Field3
0       0             8          45          45     45     45     45
1       1             9          45          45     45     45     45
2       2            10          45          45     45     45     45
3       3            11          45          45     45     45     45
4       4            12          45          45     45     45     45
5       5            13          45          45     45     45     45
6       6            14          45          45     45     45     45
7       7            15          45          45     45     45     45
```

Sample input data for the above example:

```
data = {'Sr.No.': list(range(8)),
        'CompanyNames': list(range(8, 16)),
        'YourChoice1': ['45','45','45','45','45','45','45','45'],
        'YourChoice2': ['45','45','45','45','45','45','45','45'],
        'Bollinger Bands': {'Field1': ['45','45','45','45','45','45','45','45'],
                            'Field2': ['45','45','45','45','45','45','45','45'],
                            'Field3':['45','45','45','45','45','45','45','45']}}
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting the error is that you have nested dicts in data. Since you only have `Bollinger Bands` as a second level dict, you can `pop` that out and `concat` that later to your dataframe.

```
bbands = data.pop('Bollinger Bands')
new_df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data), pd.DataFrame(bbands)], axis=1).set_index('Sr.No.')
```

(I am assuming that `Sr.No.` is your index column.)

The above code will create a new dataframe without the `Bollinger Bands` part of the header. You will have to add that manually to the file and append your dataframe to the same file.

```
with open('my_csv.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write("      |     |     |     |Bollinger Bands|        |        \n")
    new_df.to_csv(f, sep='|')
```

I am not sure why you would need leading and trailing `|`. So I have omitted in the solution.

Comment: Why don't you concatenate both, and write the header yourselves, just like how I've done in the answer above.